# Selector for filtered items with jQuery tableSorter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

This got into my head lately and honestly I think its worth asking. Here is the thingy..

I have a table , just like any other ordinary table with jquery tablesorter plugin with the filter widget.   On the very right of the table columns I've put a checkbox and above that column, on the table headers on that columhn I have another checkbox which has a function  linked to it, so that when it gets clicked all the checkboxes get updated with this checkbox's value . 
This is not very fancy or sophisticated and I have two way of accomplishing this .. either using a jquery selector or plain old javascript.

so here is what I want todo .. I want to filter elements of the table, then click the checkbox on the header , and I want to affect the row's checkboxes that were filtered with the plugin.

anyone has something to say about this?
thanks .

Comment: this question can be reworded to fit the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have a demo set up for that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4226/)

```
$( function() {
    // using .on() which requires jQuery 1.7+
    $( 'table' ).on( 'tablesorter-initialized', function() {

        // class name to add on tr when checkbox is checked
        var highlightClass = 'checked',
        // resort the table after the checkbox is modified?
        resort = true,
        // if a server side database needs to be updated, do it here
        serverCallback = function( table, inputElement ) {},

        $table = $( this ),
        c = this.config,
        wo = c && c.widgetOptions,
        // include sticky header checkbox; if installed
        $sticky = c && wo.$sticky || '',
        doChecky = function( c, col ) {
            $table
                .children( 'tbody' )
                .children( 'tr:visible' )
                .children( 'td:nth-child( ' + ( parseInt( col, 10 ) + 1 ) + ' )' )
                .find( 'input[type=checkbox]' )
                .each( function() {
                    this.checked = c;
                    $( this ).trigger( 'change' );
                });
        };

        $table
            .children( 'tbody' )
            .on( 'change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
                // ignore change if updating all rows
                if ( $table[0].ignoreChange ) { return; }
                var col, $this = $( this );
                $this.closest( 'tr' ).toggleClass( highlightClass, this.checked );
                $this.trigger( 'updateCell', [ $this.closest( 'td' ), resort ] );
                // if your server side database needs more parameters, add them here sent to the callback
                serverCallback( $table[0], this );
                // uncheck header if any checkboxes are unchecked
                if ( !this.checked ) {
                    $table.add( $sticky ).find( 'thead input[type=checkbox]' ).prop( 'checked', false );
                }
            })
            .end()
            .add( $sticky )
            .find( 'thead input[type=checkbox]' )
            // Click on checkbox in table header to toggle all inputs
            .on( 'change', function() {
                // prevent updateCell for every cell
                $table[0].ignoreChange = true;
                var c = this.checked,
                    col = $( this ).closest( 'th' ).attr( 'data-column' );
                doChecky( c, col );
                // update main & sticky header
                $table.add( $sticky ).find( 'th[data-column=' + col + '] input[type=checkbox]' ).prop( 'checked', c );
                $table.children( 'tbody' ).children( 'tr:visible' ).toggleClass( highlightClass, c );
                // update all at once
                $table[0].ignoreChange = false;
                $table.trigger( 'update', [ resort ] );
            })
            .on( 'mouseup', function() {
                return false;
            });

    });

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders','filter'],
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: 'checkbox' }
        }
    });
});
```

Just make sure to include the [`parser-input-select.js` file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js)

Comment: Hi Mottie !  This is a good start , would this work for the filter widget?

Comment: Actually !! IT DOES !!

Comment: hey howwer, when I add the filter widget , It works perfectly , but i log this error in my console:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
How do you get rid off this errors?

Comment: In which browser? Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: I am using jquery V 1.11.It wokrs perfectly , but the error log annoys my fellow programmers lol. this is all the stack trace. 

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child jquery.js:1471Sizzle.error jquery.js:1471Sizzle.selectors.preFilter.CHILD jquery.js:1592tokenize jquery2.js:2063select jquery2.js:2473Sizzle jquery.js:880Sizzle.matches jquery2.js:1409jQuery.filter jquery2.js:2661jQuery.each.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery2.js:3010doChecky myfunction.js:84(anonymous function) myfunction.js:116jQuery.event.dispatch jquery2.js:4624jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle

Comment: And also its worth mentioning I am using the migrate plugin.

Comment: I commented out the next line and got rid of the error.
//.children( 'td:nth-child( ' + ( parseInt( col, 10 ) + 1 ) + ' )' )

Comment: And once again thanks Mottie !

Comment: Are you sure you're using the most [up-to-date migrate code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js)? I [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4223/) to include it, and I'm not seeing any messages.

Comment: yes Migrate is uptodate.This is your demo , I just added the filter plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4224/
If you filter for a matching value , like abc , then you will see the error.  I commented out line 24 of the js and got it to work , but I dont know what I stopped from working XD

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that you had to *use* the filter LOL ;)... if you change all `input` selectors to `input[type=checkbox]` it'll work properly. I've updated the answer above.